# How to add custom marker in kml file?

Tags: kml, marker

How to add custom marker in KML file ? Why my code doesn't work ?

**New edited code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Style id="mycustommarker">
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>http://www.exemple.com/image.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name>Name</name>
<description>Description</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>-8.291014,47.813155,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute of the IconStyle must be a relative file or absolute URL. The value "exemple.com/img.png" in your example is not a fully qualified URL.

Example:

```
 <Style id="randomColorIcon">
      <IconStyle>        
         <Icon>
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/airports.png</href>
         </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
   </Style>
```

Here's a working example to try.
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Style/yellow-paddle.kml

More details can be found in the KML reference documentation:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#iconstyle

Also, when in doubt, use the [KML validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm) to check your KML. You'll notice 3 errors including use of a non-standard namespace - should use xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" not "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2".

Comment: Thank you Jason. The href I've used in my question is just an exemple, the real mine is good. I've tried the KML Validator and there was 2 errors in my code. I succeeded to solve 1 of the 2 errors, but I really don't know how to solve the last problem... Could someone tell me what to do ? (I edit my question with the last code.)

Comment: New edited code :     
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Style id="mycustommarker">
    <IconStyle>
    <Icon>
    <href>http://www.exemple.com/image.png</href>
    </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
    <name>Name</name>
    <description>Description</description>
    <Point>
    <coordinates>-8.291014,47.813155,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
    </Placemark>
    </kml>

Comment: xmlns namespace still invalid. <kml xmlns="`http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2`">.. Also example.com in href must be fully qualified URL; e.g. `http://host/image.png` ?? See working example and compare syntax to your KML.

Comment: KML Validator say I've only got 1 error, that seems to be the 'style' element. So I don't understand what's wrong with xmlns namespace... And for the href, I can't add the true link in my messages but the true is good. (Sorry, I've got difficulties, I don't understand English very well. Could you give me a working exemple ?) Thank you again.

Comment: Well, now KML Validator says I haven't error, yess !! But it doesn't work either... It works, but I still have got the default google icon... My href is : h t t p : / / w w w . m y d o m a i n . c o m / i m a g e . p n g (within spaces)

Comment: Check out this [example](http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Style/yellow-paddle.kml). Post back the KML you have into your question.

Comment: Thank you again Jason, but this morning my custom icon has miraculously appeared ! Any operation with my kml file seems to take a very long time to appear, that explain why I had so many problems... Do you have an idea of the reason of this long time to proceed ? I've still got some changes to do and it isn't practical...

Comment: Try to load the icons in a web browser to make sure they load quickly. You may want to check if your saved places file is large. You should post a separate question to address a new problem.

Comment: Thank you. For the moment my site is in localhost, may be it's the problem. I gonna see when it will be online.